# Showing image slowly before page load

Tags: jquery, preloader

How can i have the preloader like this [website](http://sarehnouri.com/)
i mean the image showing slowly .
**BUT**
I want to achieve this by `windows.load` ?
any idea ?
THx

**UPDATE**

```
 function initSplash(){
var block = $("#splashLogoBlock");
var active = 0;
var pause = 300;
var timer = 500;
var count = 11;
var idTimeout;

for(var i=1; i< count + 1; i++){
    $('<div class="splashLogoShower shower' + i + '"></div>').insertBefore($(".splashLogo"));
}
```

it used this js .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not pre-loading data, this is just animation.

You can make some jQuery animations:

```
$(element).animate({height: "20px"}, 500, function() {
   //this code will run after animation complete
   console.log('animation comlpeted');

   //or even redirect if you want
   window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
});
```

for more details please check [**jQuery animate() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

**--- UPDATE---**

Here is the exact example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/7R4Sq/

**--- UPDATE 2 ---**

Another example with same page loader: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/7R4Sq/2/

Comment: is that possible to convert as a loading ?

Comment: Yes, you can play with `.animate({ cssName1 : cssVal1, cssName2:cssVal2})` and change position and opacity to each element you want.

Comment: but this site use one element (image). How is that possible with css3 ?

Comment: see updated answer. I wrote same example fiddle for you.

Comment: Thx man , thx alot . the question is : should i create a page for this and after that redirect to main page ?  
i dont think this can be a loading 
 sry i'm not good at jquery

Comment: In your case this will be easiest way to create separate page.

Comment: yes , it's the easeiset way but it's not the way i want . create a page before index.html is not good for seo .  
any idea to not create a another page for that ?

Comment: In that case you need one overflow div over all content with 100% width and height and after animation is complete, just hide it out. See update 2

Answer (score 1):

That website is not "pre-loading" data.

Watch the URL when you go there, and when the animation ends -- sarehnouri.com can simply be displaying an animation, and then `.done`, it redirects you to sarehnouri.com/main which is not the same page.

It could be as simple as...

```
$(function() {
    displayAnimation().done(function() { window.location.href = "/main";
});
```

Or you could just look at their source code and see what is actually going on.

Comment: Yes you right , can i achieve this by preloading and windows.load function ?

Comment: @user3642164 `windows` is not correct, `window` is the global object. And you aren't pre-loading anything. It's displaying the animation, and then redirecting you to the main page.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually a bad example. Just have it go to the real page and do something like $('html').removeClass('loading') inside a window.load event binding

Comment: @Michael the tricky part is knowing when the animation is complete.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes, and for that reason I suggest a preloading animation that has such a rigid length is best avoided. Unless you want to slow down the loading of the website on purpose (bad idea). Just have a nice graphic that rotates/pulses until the window.load event fires.

Comment: thx . btw that website use an image. how can i show it word by word as it does

Comment: @user3642164 you need to create animation before. check my answer below.

Comment: @Michael that's not a loading graphic. Their website is not that slow. It's like a title page -- they want the animation shown before sending you to the actual page.

Comment: this site use one element (image). How is that possible with css3 ?